# Light bulb keeps going out, but isn't burned out.

Tags: electrical

Recessed light (can) in living room ceiling went out. When I touched it to replace it, it went back on, only to go out again the next day. I screwed it in tighter and it went on, only to go out again the next day. If it were a heat issue, it should come back on after it goes out, but it doesn't. Is this indicating a loose connection to the lighting fixture and is it dangerous? (Living in Oregon)

Answer (score 2):

I'd try bending the hot contact in the socket out a little bit or a different bulb. If the problem persists I'd be inspecting the connections inside the junction box.

- Try a different bulb (swap in a known working bulb, and swap this one out to a known working can light).
- Try bending the contact out (the pin inside the socket).
- Inspect the connections (remove the three screws holding the can light housing in. Pull it out of the ceiling and now you can access the junction box).

Rub the threads of new bulbs in your hair (to lubricate them) before you insert them.

Comment: I would secònd the "try a new bulb". I have had CFLs that fail this way.

Answer (score 1):

Or corroded or cracked terminals in the lamp socket.  Those sockets tend to be fairly standard, and you can probably obtain a replacement socket. My local hardware store stocks all that kind of stuff, but they're pretty special.  1000bulbs and other websites also have good selection.

Assuming you really want to stay with incandescent in that location.  Consider quality LEDs, which have won on the merits, despite having to compete with long-term government contracts to subsidize CFLs.  They have also solved the problems with color temperature and CRI, and you can get any color you want, as long as it's not black!

Comment: Aren't incandescents actually illegal to sell nowadays?